# Webview does not load a particular website

Tags: android, webview

I have a Webview in which i am trying to load [this url](https://www.xfinityprepaid.net/CustomerActivation/CustomerActivation)

But the webview is blank, i have added internet permission in manifest, tried to load google.com in the same webview and it loads fine.

Tried loading same url in phone browser(chrome) and it loads fine

This is my code :

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewmain);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
}
private class WebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.", source: https://www.xfinityprepaid.net/CustomerActivation/vendor.23a90aa3d57e711f4e5c.bundle.js (1)
 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "ERROR", source: https://www.xfinityprepaid.net/CustomerActivation/vendor.23a90aa3d57e711f4e5c.bundle.js (1)file:external/boringssl/src/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c ;Line:186;Function:ASN1_get_object


 D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: adservice.google.co.in get result from proxy gai_error = 0
 D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: match.adsrvr.org get result from proxy gai_error = 0
 D/OpenSSLLib: OpensslErr:Module:12(116:176); file:external/boringssl/src/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c ;Line:186;Function:ASN1_get_object
 D/OpenSSLLib: OpensslErr:Module:12(116:176); file:external/boringssl/src/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c ;Line:186;Function:ASN1_get_object
 D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: www.facebook.com get result from proxy gai_error = 0
 D/OpenSSLLib: OpensslErr:Module:12(116:176); file:external/boringssl/src/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c ;Line:186;Function:ASN1_get_object
 D/OpenSSLLib: OpensslErr:Module:12(116:176); file:external/boringssl/src/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c ;Line:186;Function:ASN1_get_object
 D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: mtk hostname=www.xfinityprepaid.net; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
```

any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the similar issue. after a long research, i added so many codes its start working. this is not the right answer, but my Angular website starts working on adding this code. check and please let me know if it's helpful.

```
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);

    webView.loadUrl(url);

    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.clearView();
    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + this.getPackageName() + "/databases/");
    }
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.OFF);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.setInitialScale(1);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: most of the things are repeated, i removed that other things i just copy pasted it works.

Comment: with this properties, works: webview.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webview.settings.domStorageEnabled = true

Comment: `setDomStorageEnabled(true)` was the missing piece for me as well

Answer (score 0):

Adding those settings alone helped me show my angular website.

```java
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```